# CMake: create single shared-library from all third-party static library along with C++ files for Android

Tags: cmake, android-ndk

I've been facing this problem for days and have tried many solutions but none of them worked for me. Another question was how to combine two .so files, but this is not what I'm trying to do here.(as it's not possible from whatever I've read as well)

*System_used* : Ubuntu 16.04

*Problem* : For a particular C++ code which used the third-party fftw3 library, I combined the code and the FFT library with `target_link_library()` command in CMakeLists.txt, which builds a shared library and works when I run it on eclipse. After building for Android architecture and doing the same process it throws the error `Error:error: undefined reference to 'fftw_execute'` when I run it on Android Studio.

The steps I followed were:

1. FFT library was compiled into an .so (shared library) for each android architecture. (armeabi , arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64, mips, mips64)
2. The resulting libfftw3.so files for each of them, were tested successfully on Android.
3. Wrote a cmake file to turn my C++ code (mod.h, mod.cpp) into shared library along with linked third-party library libfftw3.so. The command used in cmake was `target_link_libraries(shared-lib-name ${FFT_LIBRARIES})`
4. Took an android toolchain file, and ran the following command for ***each architecture***: (the following is for *mips64*)

> cmake .. -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=17 -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/toolchain/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NDK=/path/to/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle -DFFT_INCLUDES=/path/to/header/include -DFFT_LIBRARIES=/path/to/library/lib/libfftw3.so -DANDROID_ABI=mips64

This gave me shared-lib-name.so (which linked to libfftw for the given ABI) for each architecture. On putting the `shared-lib-name.so` of every Architecture in the Android project, and running the build, the following is noticed.

The mod.cpp functions are correctly recognized but it gives an undefined reference error when using some fftw library function like `fftw_execute`.

Comment: You must put libfftw3.so into your APK, too. Before Lollipop, you also have to System.load("fftw3") before you load you library that depends on it. you

Comment: Yes, I did that my question was how to combine the shared library which my cpp code uses into a new shared library.

Comment: You cannot 'inject' a prebuilt shared library into your shared library, or add your code to a prebuilt shared library. These tricks work with static libraries, though.

Comment: Even injecting the static library would work great for me as long as it gets injected and recognized in Android. How would that be done, though I doubt the injection will be done in cmake

Comment: If you have `libfftw3.a` for Android, you can use it to build your shared library instead of `libfftw3.so`. So you will end up with a single **.so** file.

Comment: I changed the question so that it can be combined with a static file as well. Could you please share how to do it for the same so that I can upvote your answer :)

Comment: Your question remains essentially same: you want to use prebuilt `libfftw3.so` with your C++ code as one library. The answer is, this isn't possible. You can build a separate dependent `.so` file, pack both files into your APK, and load them both (in the correct order).

Comment: My question actually changed to how a static library, i.e,  `.a` file be combined with C++ code into a single `.so`.

Comment: please rewrite your question to make it clear which is static prebuilt library and which is not. Or open a new question about it (it seems to me a very different question).

Comment: From my understanding of the latest question, you're facing an issue with Android Studio build such that it's giving a "undefined reference error" but the entire ```mod``` c++ code is correctly recognized, is that right? You could add your .so files inside ```jniLibs``` folder under ```app``` (or whatever you've called) module. Also posting the ```CMakeLists.txt``` would help...